# Find a node with a specific 'style' attribute xpath in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xpath

So I'm using Mechanize in Ruby to do some website scraping and want to find all nodes with a specific `style` attribute.

I want to return all nodes with a style attribute that has specific `top` value on the webpage.

The HTML will look like this:

```
<div id="c11285" style="position:absolute;top:1px;left:333px;width:65px;height:226px;overflow:hidden;background-color:transparent;z-index:10;border: 1px solid #000" onclick="">
```

In this case I cannot use the id, because each variation of the page has different ids so I want to search by the `top` value in the `style` attribute which in this case is `1px`.

I've tried using `webPage.search("div['style=top: 1px;']")`
However, this does not work as `px` seems to cause an error.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It scans all elements and return those which have top:1px in style attribute.

```
//*[contains(@style, 'top:1px')]
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I ended up finding the answer using CSS selectors which turned out to be `div[style*='top:1px;']`